# What are the drawbacks (if any) in using Agile and CMMI process templates?

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I am currently using Scrum for my TFS project template and I really want to start using some of the product planning, project management, and bug backlog features that Agile and CMMI offer.

I have found a lot of documentation based on the ***differences*** between Agile and CMMI through these links: 
[Link 1: Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058313/what-is-the-difference-between-cmmi-and-agile)
[Link 2: Social Microsoft Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8e3d872-d815-4be6-96ff-fdefdaad1b47/major-differences-between-msf-40-agile-and-cmmi?forum=vstsmsf)
[Link 3: Official Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752.aspx)
[Link 4: Similar Official Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have not found anything that can represent **real drawbacks** to either of these approaches. These are some of the questions regarding downsides that I have been thinking about:

Would one template be more effective at one particular aspect than another?
 
Are there any performance issues that would make one template better than another?
 
Is there a learning curve in implementing either one of these templates?
Would using a process template like CMMI for a smaller team overall hurt productivity than something simpler like Agile?

These questions are ***not concrete***, meaning I am not specifically looking for answers to these questions. If there are no significant drawbacks to using Agile or CMMI, then I will simply choose a process template based on preference of the features offered.

---

**Requirements:**

I am working with a small team (5 or 6 people) for a large company that follows regulated procedures to submit changes and would like to have easy navigation to specific work items based on sub-areas.

---

Yes this sounds like we should go for CMMI, but for a small dev team, I am not sure if this template would beneficial as far as time spent on developing the template than to just simply use Agile.

Comment: It's hard to tell what requirements you have for a process template, generally, if you are working agile, use the MSF Agile or Scrum, if you need more traceability use CMMI. Why not create a http://visualstudio.com account and try them out?

Comment: @DaveShaw I added more background info to what my situation is. Please do not hesitate if you need more info

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you seriously consider wither either of the MSF templates are for you. I would suggest that unless you are Microsoft Consulting Services or you are not doing agile then you should be on the Scrum template (forget the name its about the practices that are supported).

http://nakedalm.com/agile-vs-scrum-process-templates-team-foundation-server/

There is, in my opinion, no reason to ever use one of the MSF templates.